# What do I have to do to add a new hard drive to an existing Linux system?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, installation

I have a new mechanical hard drive I would like to add to my Ubuntu 10.10 system.

Currently, I have a 128 GB SSD hard drive which contains my whole / partition. I would now like to add a 1 TB HDD to the system, but without reinstalling Ubuntu.

Is this just a simple matter of plugging the new hard drive in or is there something more?

Comment: You probably meant 1TB HDD, as 1GB would be a quite old drive.

Comment: Indeed! Edited now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes basically it's sufficient to plug in the new drive and boot up the computer. It should be automatically recognized, though you still need to partition and format it in order to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple matter of plugging the thing in, and possible searching for an appropriate driver.
It should probably be empty save for a few "included programs" in many cases but you can delete those.

If you want to move your /home folder to that drive to keep strain off your SSD, you'd be advised to check out [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving).